# reverse list - scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to reverse a list, here's my code:

```
(define (reverse list)
  (if (null? list) 
     list
      (list (reverse (cdr list)) (car list))))
```

so if i enter (reverse '(1 2 3 4)), I want it to come out as (4 3 2 1), but right now it's not giving me that.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you expect your code to work with either or both of circular lists and improper lists?

Comment: instead of your `(list A B)` use `(append A (list B))`.

Answer (score 16):

The natural way to recur over a list is not the best way to solve this problem. Using `append`, as suggested in the accepted answer pointed by @lancery, is not a good idea either - and anyway if you're learning your way in Scheme it's best if you try to implement the solution yourself, I'll show you what to do, but first a tip - don't use `list` as a parameter name, that's a built-in procedure and you'd be overwriting it. Use other name, say, `lst`.

It's simpler to reverse a list by means of a helper procedure that accumulates the result of consing each element at the *head* of the result, this will have the effect of reversing the list - incidentally, the helper procedure is tail-recursive. Here's the general idea, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (reverse lst)
  (<???> lst '()))                       ; call the helper procedure

(define (reverse-aux lst acc)
  (if <???>                              ; if the list is empty
      <???>                              ; return the accumulator
      (reverse-aux <???>                 ; advance the recursion over the list
                   (cons <???> <???>)))) ; cons current element with accumulator
```

Of course, in real-life you wouldn't implement `reverse` from scratch, there's a built-in [procedure](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._reverse%29%29) for that.

Comment: I wouldn't advise against using 'list' as a parameter name - the lexical scoping of Scheme is part of its beauty.  I would recommend not to conflate a parameter with a 'global' function; one of the errors in the posers code.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a recursive procedure that describes an iterative process (tail recursive) of reversing a list in Scheme

```
(define (reverse lst)
  (define (go lst tail)
    (if (null? lst) tail
        (go (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) tail))))
  (go lst ())))
```

Using substitution model for (reverse (list 1 2 3 4))

```
;; (reverse (list 1 2 3 4))                                                                                                                           
;; (go (list 1 2 3 4) ())                                                                                                                             
;; (go (list 2 3 4) (list 1))                                                                                                                         
;; (go (list 3 4) (list 2 1))                                                                                                                         
;; (go (list 4) (list 3 2 1))                                                                                                                         
;; (go () (list 4 3 2 1))                                                                                                                             
;; (list 4 3 2 1)
```

Here is a recursive procedure that describes a recursive process (not tail recursive) of reversing a list in Scheme

```
(define (reverse2 lst)
  (if (null? lst) ()
    (append (reverse2 (cdr lst)) (list (car lst)))))

(define (append l1 l2)
  (if (null? l1) l2
      (cons (car l1) (append (cdr l1) l2))))
```

Using substitution model for (reverse2 (list 1 2 3 4))

```
;; (reverse2 (list 1 2 3 4))                                                                                                                          
;; (append (reverse2 (list 2 3 4)) (list 1))                                                                                                          
;; (append (append (reverse2 (list 3 4)) (list 2)) (list 1))                                                                                          
;; (append (append (append (reverse2 (list 4)) (list 3)) (list 2)) (list 1))                                                                          
;; (append (append (append (append (reverse2 ()) (list 4)) (list 3)) (list 2)) (list 1))                                                              
;; (append (append (append (append () (list 4)) (list 3)) (list 2)) (list 1))                                                                         
;; (append (append (append (list 4) (list 3)) (list 2)) (list 1))                                                                                     
;; (append (append (list 4 3) (list 2)) (list 1))                                                                                                     
;; (append (list 4 3 2) (list 1))                                                                                                                     
;; (list 4 3 2 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tail recursive approach using a named `let`:

```
(define (reverse lst)
  (let loop ([lst lst] [lst-reversed '()])
    (if (empty? lst)
        lst-reversed
        (loop (rest lst) (cons (first lst) lst-reversed)))))
```

This is basically the same approach as having a helper function with an accumulator argument as in Oscar's answer, where the `loop` binding after `let` makes the let into an inner function you can call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `build-list` procedure:

```
(define reverse
  (lambda (l)
    (let ((len (length l)))
      (build-list len
                  (lambda (i)
                    (list-ref l (- len i 1)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works but it is not a tail recursive procedure:

```
(define (rev lst)
 (if (null? lst)
     '()
      (append (rev (cdr lst)) (car lst))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tail recursive solution:

```
(define (reverse oldlist)
    (define (t-reverse oldlist newlist)
        (if (null? oldlist)
            newlist
            (t-reverse (cdr oldlist) (cons (car oldlist) newest))))
    (t-reverse oldlist '()))
```

Comment: isn't this exactly the same as the first solution in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42236802/849891) though, up to variables renaming. :)

Comment: Yep, that looks like the same

Answer (score 0):

Just left fold the list using cons:

```
(define (reverse list) (foldl cons null list))
```

This is also efficient because foldl is tail recursive and there is no need for append. This can also be done point-free (using curry from racket):

```
(define reverse (curry foldl cons null))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(define reverse?
  (lambda (l)
    (define reverse-aux?
      (lambda (l col)
        (cond 
          ((null? l) (col ))
          (else 
            (reverse-aux? (cdr l) 
                          (lambda () 
                            (cons (car l) (col))))))))
    (reverse-aux? l (lambda () (quote ())))))
(reverse? '(1 2 3 4) )
```

One more answer similar to Oscar's. I have just started learning scheme, so excuse me in case you find issues :).

Answer (score -1):

There's actually no need for appending or filling the body with a bunch of lambdas.

```
(define (reverse items)
  (if (null? items)
      '()
      (cons (reverse (cdr items)) (car items))))
```

Comment: I think you meant `append` instead of `cons`. Running `(reverse '(1 2 3))` yields `'(((() . 3) . 2) . 1)`

Comment: yep, you're right! @Salvatore Rapisarda got it right

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be better to use append instead of cons

```
(define (myrev l)
  (if (null? l)
      '()
      (append (myrev (cdr l)) (list (car l)))
  )
)
```

this another version with tail recursion

```
(define (myrev2 l)
  (define (loop l acc) 
    (if (null? l)
        acc
        (loop (cdr l) (append (list (car l)) acc ))
    )
  )
  (loop l '())
)
```