# Scheme output has extra parenthesis and periods

Tags: list, scheme, racket, reverse

I started learning Scheme today, and wanted to write a function that would reverse a list (only surface level, nested lists stay in the same order).

Heres the function I made:

```
(define reverse (lambda (lst)
                  (if (> (length lst) 0)
                      (cons (reverse(cdr lst)) (car lst))
                      '()
                      )))
```

I thought it would just continuously add the values before everything after it so in the end it's reversed, but when doing `(reverse '(5 12 31 7 98 13))`, I should get `(13 98 7 31 12 5)`, but instead I get `'((((((() . 13) . 98) . 7) . 31) . 12) . 5)`. How come it's adding periods and parenthesis instead of adding the number to the list?

Comment: Because the second argument to `cons` is a single value, not a pair. That makes it an *improper list*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058246/reverse-list-scheme isn't *quite* a duplicate because the code is slightly different, but should give you ideas.

Comment: Compare `(cons 1 '(2))` to `(cons '(1) 2)`.

Comment: try `(list 1 2 3)`, `(cons 1 (cons 2 3))`, `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))`, `'(1 . (2 . 3))` and `'(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(list x y ..... z)` list structure is constructed like this in Scheme:

```
(cons x
      (cons y
            …
            …
            (cons z '())))
```

if you use `append` instead of `cons` and put your `(car lst)` into a list of its own, your code will work:

```
(define reverse 
   (lambda (lst)
     (if (> (length lst) 0)
         ;;(cons (reverse (cdr lst))       (car lst) )
         (append (reverse (cdr lst)) (list (car lst)))
         '()
     )))
```

Answer (score 1):

The list `(13 98 7 31 12 5)` is a visualization of the pairs `(13 . (98 . (7 . (31 . (12 . (5 . ()))))))`. If the `cdr` is a pair or the empty list the dot and one set of parens is omitted. The code to create this structure is `(cons 13 (cons 98 (cons 7 (cons 31 (cons 12 (cons 5 '()))))))` while the structure your function creates is `(cons (cons (cons (cons (cons (cons 13 '()) 98) 7) 31) 12) 5)`.

When iterating a list you always do it in order. eg. `(1 2 3)` is quite difficult to do in reverse. However when creating lists you always do them from **end to beginning**. eg. `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))` will have to evaluate the `cons` with 3 before the one with 2 etc. This can be used for a very efficent `reverse` using an accumulator:

```
(define (reverse lst acc)
  (if (null? lst)
      acc
      (reverse (cdr lst) 
               (cons (car lst) acc))))
```

So imagine calling this `(reverse '(1 2 3) '())`:

```
(reverse '(1 2 3) '())        ; => 
(reverse '(2 3) (cons 1 '())) ; ==> 
(reverse '(3) (cons 2 '(1)))  ; ==> 
(reverse '() (cons 3 '(2 1))) ; ==> 
'(3 2 1)
```